# How can I download a file from an S3 bucket with wget by Object owner?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am a beginner in aws and I have a problem.
Problem is:
Is it possible to download an object from S3 bucket via the object owner using the wget command from Elastic container service?

I have defined the policies, but it seems that these policies have no effect and aws considers the download request from outside and does not find the object and issues a 403 message.

Is there any other solution?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: What do you mean "by Object owner"? Also, before you run `wget` from ECS, make sure that it runs from your desktop or EC2. What if you make the bucket public? Finally, you need to provide much more information (like, bucket configuration and policy) in order for us to help you!

Comment: wget does not understand how to get AWS credentials and sign requests.  You'll either need to use a presigned URL, or just use the AWS SDK to get the file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I activate it as presigned URL, wget shows a long length URL error.